# Multicolumn within ifthenelse becomes misaligned

Tags: multicolumn

I want to write a command that will produce a table, but can also add one multicolumn with an optional argument's contents in it. I tried to do this using `ifthenelse` to check if the optional argument is empty, but something about having the brackets around multicolumn gives me a `mispaced \omit` error, and causes the column to be misaligned.

Here is what the command would look like:

```
\newcommand{\namecol}[1][]{
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{tabular}{|rlrl|}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{}{%
        \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{#1} \\
    }
    a & b & c & d \\
    e & f & g & h \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
}
```

and below are the results of calling `\namecol` and `\namecol[x]`, respectively:

[image: multicol misalignment]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this fulfill your expectations?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\namecol}[1][\relax]{
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{tabular}{|rlrl|}
    \ifx\relax#1\relax\else
        \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{#1} \\
        \fi
    a & b & c & d \\
    e & f & g & h \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
}

\namecol

\namecol[x]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing, thanks. That's exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: this will not work if you use `\namecol[zz]` for example.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, you're right, I think. Thanks!

Comment: please fix the answer (`\ifx\relax#1` not `\ifx#1\relax`)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks! (This is precisely what I did, I relaxed first and now fixed it. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `\multicolumn` has to be the first object (after macro expansion) in the cell, but `\ifthenelse` inserts other things and, when `\multicolumn` is eventually found, it is too late.

A simpler approach is with `xparse`, where we can test whether the optional argument has been given with the expandable test `\IfValueT`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse} % not needed if using LaTeX released on or after 2020-10-01

\NewDocumentCommand{\namecol}{o}{%
  \begin{table}[htp!]% <--- not just h!
  \begin{tabular}{|rlrl|}
  \IfValueT{#1}{\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{#1} \\}
  a & b & c & d \\
  e & f & g & h \\
  \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
}

\begin{document}

\namecol

\namecol[x]

\end{document}
```

[image]